# How to pass sequence of image through Conv2D in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I have a sequence of 5 images that I want to pass through a CNN sequentially. A single input will have size: `(5, width, height, channels)` and I want to pass each image in the sequence in order to a 2D CNN, concatenate all 5 outputs at some layer and then feed to an LSTM. My model looks something like this:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, LSTM, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

# Feed images in sequential order here
inputs = Input(shape=(128, 128, 3))
x = Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
...
# Concatenate sequence outputs here
x = LSTM(8)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
outputs = Dense(5, activation='sigmoid')

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

Eventually I want to concatenate all 5 outputs together at some point in the network and feed them to an LSTM but I am having trouble figuring out how to feed sequence of images in order to a 2D convolutional layer. I have looked into 3D convolutional layers and the `ConvLSTM2D` layer but I want to figure out how I can do it this way instead.

Comment: Coincidentally i had the same question today. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53488768/keras-functional-api-combine-cnn-model-with-a-rnn-to-to-look-at-sequences-of-im